# Rcpp and int64 NA value

Tags: r, rcpp, na, bit64

How can I pass an NA value from Rcpp to R in a 64 bit vector?

My first approach would be:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]                                     
Rcpp::NumericVector foo() {
  Rcpp::NumericVector res(2);

  int64_t val = 1234567890123456789;
  std::memcpy(&(res[0]), &(val), sizeof(double));
  res[1] = NA_REAL;

  res.attr("class") = "integer64";
  return res;
}
```

But it yields

```
#> foo()
integer64
[1] 1234567890123456789 9218868437227407266
```

I need to get

```
#> foo()
integer64
[1] 1234567890123456789 <NA>
```

Comment: You can't use `NA_REAL` after the `memcpy` because the bit pattern is at that point the one of a `int64`.

Comment: I'd also edit the title.  The _default 64 bit NA_ is just `NA_real` which is not what your question is about.

Comment: But the memcpy copies only 64 bits (`sizeof(double)`) right? So `res[0]` gets 64 bits from  `val` and then setting `res[1] = ...` uses the next 64 bits. I agree with the outcome, but don't really follow your first comment.

Comment: I had hoped that `NA_real` uses the same bit pattern that the bit64 package uses (`1000...`). I guess I was wrong there.

Comment: The whole point is that _the content_ of the vector is then _bit by bit_ an `int64_t` that is merely "parked" inside a `double` vector (aka `NumericVector`).  There is no magic logic copy.  Jems is doing _all_ the hard work by hand.  Including mapping NAs.

Comment: I've programmed for a few years now and I think I can conclude that _hope_ is not a valid long-term strategy.  ;-)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense! Thanks for the background!

Comment: Interestingly, using `std::memcpy(&(res[1]), &(NA_REAL), sizeof(double));` doesn't work...

Comment: That. Is. What. I. Have. Been. Trying. To. Explain.  Look at eg the R source for the existing NA defines. Look at some packages using `int64` and see what they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I think I found an answer... (not beautiful, but working).

### Short Answer:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]                                     
Rcpp::NumericVector foo() {
  Rcpp::NumericVector res(2);

  int64_t val = 1234567890123456789;
  std::memcpy(&(res[0]), &(val), sizeof(double));

  # This is the magic:
  int64_t v = 1ULL << 63;
  std::memcpy(&(res[1]), &(v), sizeof(double));

  res.attr("class") = "integer64";
  return res;
}
```

which results in

```
#> foo()
integer64
[1] 1234567890123456789 <NA>
```

### Longer Answer

Inspecting how `bit64` stores an `NA`

```r
# the last value is the max value of a 64 bit number
a <- bit64::as.integer64(c(1, 2, NA, 9223372036854775807))
a
#> integer64
#> [1] 1    2    <NA> <NA>
bit64::as.bitstring(a[3])
#> [1] "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
bit64::as.bitstring(a[4])
#> [1] "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

we see that it is a `10000...`. This can be recreated in `Rcpp` with `int64_t val = 1ULL << 63;`. Using `memcpy()` instead of a simple assign with `=` ensures that no bits are changed!

Comment: Yes. If you look at some source packages you will see corresponding `#define` statement to declare one bit pattern (often either `min` or `max`) to be the NA value.

Answer (score 7):

It's really much, much simpler. We have the behaviour of an `int64` in R offered by (several) add-on packages the best of which is `bit64` giving us the `integer64` S3 class and associated behavior.

And it [defines the NA](https://github.com/cran/bit64/blob/master/src/integer64.h#L28) internally as follows:

```
#define NA_INTEGER64 LLONG_MIN
```

And that is all that there is. R and its packages are foremost C code, and `LLONG_MIN` exists there and goes (almost) back all the way to founding fathers.

There are two lessons here.  The first is the extension of IEEE defining NaN and Inf for *floating point values*.  R actually goes way beyond and adds `NA` for *each of its types*.  In pretty much the way above: by reserving one particular bit pattern. (Which, in one case, is the birthday of one of the two original R creators.)

The other is to admire the metric ton of work Jens did with the `bit64` package and *all* the required conversion and operator functions.  *Seamlessly* converting all possibly values, including NA, NaN, Inf, ... is no small task.

And it is a neat topic that not too many people know. I am glad you asked the question because we now have a record here.